# Data fetched is not showing on the material ui table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, fetch-api, material-table

My data is not showing on the console and as well as the table, the status of api call seems to be fine, data is shown in network, but when I console.log it, its not showing the array and there is also a bug that my data is not array, but when I checked it is an array data. Main error seems to be in the table mapping.

This image shows the data present in the api:
[image: This image shows the data present in the api]

I tried debugging it, it says my data is not an array, I need a solution to this and I want it to display on my table.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { token: bearer
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        const mappedData = data.map(({ id, device_name, OEM, sdk_version, deviceKey, valid_upto }) =>
          createData(id, device_name, OEM, sdk_version, deviceKey, valid_upto)
        );
        setRows(mappedData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
   
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `data.map` try `data.data.map` because your data seems to be an object not an array.

Or change

```
const data = await response.json()
```

To

```
const res = await response.json()
```

So you have something like

```
const res = await response.json()
const mappedData = res.data.map(({ id, device_name, OEM, sdk_version, deviceKey, valid_upto }) =>
          createData(id, device_name, OEM, sdk_version, deviceKey, valid_upto)
        );
```

Comment: If I may ask are you getting or posting the data, because if you are getting you shouldn't be using ```POST``` and if you are posting this is not how you ```POST``` data with Fetch. I'm confused.